# how to create a mirror variable and randomly fill it with binary values in R

Tags: r, data.table

Example of dataset

```
dar=structure(list(x1 = c(2032L, 2204L, 2204L, 1861L, 1861L, 1562L, 
1562L, 2218L, 2218L, 815L, 348L, 471L, 753L, 608L, 948L, 98L, 
39L, 836L), x2 = c(1898L, 2586L, 2924L, 2564L, 1962L, 1758L, 
1594L, 2276L, 2198L, 14L, 748L, 287L, 508L, 223L, 796L, 318L, 
371L, 727L), x3 = c(2320L, 2353L, 2353L, 2023L, 2023L, 1732L, 
1732L, 2432L, 2432L, 516L, 351L, 371L, 720L, 872L, 679L, 703L, 
674L, 514L), x4 = c(2183L, 2134L, 2134L, 2053L, 2053L, 2053L, 
2053L, 2684L, 2684L, 531L, 551L, 1L, 572L, 97L, 654L, 274L, 115L, 
436L), x5 = c(989L, 1058L, 1058L, 984L, 984L, 933L, 933L, 1070L, 
1070L, 319L, 519L, 525L, 843L, 994L, 220L, 650L, 347L, 150L), 
    x6 = c(418L, 476L, 476L, 451L, 451L, 437L, 437L, 443L, 443L, 
    966L, 661L, 844L, 588L, 389L, 537L, 983L, 516L, 137L), x7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

`Y` is binary variable. It only has 2 values either 1 or 0. I need help to create a separate variable `y1` and fill it with values derived from `y` randomly. For example, so that in `y1` opposite zeros of `y` put  90% of zeros and 10 percent of 1(ones).  And also opposite 1(ones) of `y` in `y1` put  90% of 1(ones) and 10 percent of 0.

Of course, there can be a fractional percentage, for example, in the example I gave 9 zeros, 90% of 9 is 8.1, therefore we round down, i.e. 8 zeros and 2 ones.
So we expect the result to be something like this

```
desiredoutput=structure(list(x1 = c(2032L, 2204L, 2204L, 1861L, 1861L, 1562L, 
1562L, 2218L, 2218L, 815L, 348L, 471L, 753L, 608L, 948L, 98L, 
39L, 836L), x2 = c(1898L, 2586L, 2924L, 2564L, 1962L, 1758L, 
1594L, 2276L, 2198L, 14L, 748L, 287L, 508L, 223L, 796L, 318L, 
371L, 727L), x3 = c(2320L, 2353L, 2353L, 2023L, 2023L, 1732L, 
1732L, 2432L, 2432L, 516L, 351L, 371L, 720L, 872L, 679L, 703L, 
674L, 514L), x4 = c(2183L, 2134L, 2134L, 2053L, 2053L, 2053L, 
2053L, 2684L, 2684L, 531L, 551L, 1L, 572L, 97L, 654L, 274L, 115L, 
436L), x5 = c(989L, 1058L, 1058L, 984L, 984L, 933L, 933L, 1070L, 
1070L, 319L, 519L, 525L, 843L, 994L, 220L, 650L, 347L, 150L), 
    x6 = c(418L, 476L, 476L, 451L, 451L, 437L, 437L, 443L, 443L, 
    966L, 661L, 844L, 588L, 389L, 537L, 983L, 516L, 137L), x7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), у1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

How can i do it? Thank for your help.

Comment: I notice your "desired" output is not quite what I expected. You said 90% of 9 is 8.1 so we round down to 8.. but in your desired output you have 7 vs 2 (in my answer below, I assumed this was a typo in your OP) [you can set `prop` in the `get_binary_mirror()` function to change the proportion if you want)

Answer (score 3):

Set `dar` to data.table, and use this simple get_binary_mirror function

```
data.table::setDT(dar)

get_binary_mirror <- function(val,N,prop=0.9) {
  val=as.integer(val)
  m_x = rep(val,times=floor(prop*N))
  # add opposite type the number of times of the difference in length
  m_x = c(m_x, rep(0^val, times = N-length(m_x)))
  sample(m_x)
}

dar[, y1:=get_binary_mirror(.BY, .N), by=Y]
```

Output::

```
 dar
      x1   x2   x3   x4   x5  x6 x7 Y y1
 1: 2032 1898 2320 2183  989 418  0 1  0
 2: 2204 2586 2353 2134 1058 476  0 1  1
 3: 2204 2924 2353 2134 1058 476  0 1  1
 4: 1861 2564 2023 2053  984 451  0 1  1
 5: 1861 1962 2023 2053  984 451  0 1  1
 6: 1562 1758 1732 2053  933 437  0 1  1
 7: 1562 1594 1732 2053  933 437  0 1  1
 8: 2218 2276 2432 2684 1070 443  0 1  1
 9: 2218 2198 2432 2684 1070 443  0 1  1
10:  815   14  516  531  319 966  0 0  0
11:  348  748  351  551  519 661  0 0  0
12:  471  287  371    1  525 844  0 0  0
13:  753  508  720  572  843 588  0 0  0
14:  608  223  872   97  994 389  0 0  0
15:  948  796  679  654  220 537  0 0  1
16:   98  318  703  274  650 983  0 0  0
17:   39  371  674  115  347 516  0 0  0
18:  836  727  514  436  150 137  0 0  0
```

Comment: Neat solution, upvoted! Was working on a similar construct, but that's redundant now.